# A multiple-choice examination consists of $75$ questions- Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

A multiple-choice examination consists of $75$
 questions, each having possible choices a, b, c, d, and e. Approximate the probability that a student will get at most $13$
 answers correct if she randomly guesses at each answer. (Note that, if she randomly guesses at each answer, then the probability that she gets any one answer correct is $0.2$.) Use the normal approximation to the binomial with a correction for continuity.

I tried a bit 
Binomial Problem with n = 75 P(correct answer)=0.2

Binomial probability:P(X = x)=$0.10171948927$

I am I correct?

Comment: Have you looked up the normal approximation to the binomial?  It will give you values for the expected mean and standard deviation.  Then compute the Z score...

Comment: The Binomial Distribution with $n=75$ and $p=0.2$ is correct, but the exercise asks you to use the Normal approximation (of the Binomial Distribution) instead.

Comment: Binomial probability:P(X = x)=0.10171948927
is this correct?

Comment: @JimmyR. Am I correct?

Comment: I also get $0.1017$ for _exactly_  $13$ correct answers, so that's probably right. But that's not what the question asks about.

Comment: What do we have to find?

Comment: @David Read the problem text. It asks about "the probability that a student will get at most 13 answers correct" so you need to also calculate the probability for $12,11,10,$ and so on, and add them all up. Or, you could "Use the normal approximation to the binomial with a correction for continuity", which is a lot faster.

Comment: How do I do the normal approximation to the binomial with a correction for continuity?

Comment: Can you tell me the Final answer for checking?

Comment: I sincerely doubt that your book, or your lecturer, or whatever it is you have, has given you this problem without telling you about the normal approximation. Read through that. It will be a lot better than what I can tell you here.

Comment: Cumulative Probability P(X<=13)=0.3415 ? Is it correct

Comment: I get [$0.3325$](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%28-0.5<X<13.5%29+for+X+normal+with+mean+75*0.2%2C+sd%3Dsqrt%280.2*0.8*75%29). Although the [exact answer](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=P%28-0.5<X<13.5%29+for+X+normal+with+mean+75*0.2%2C+sd%3Dsqrt%280.2*0.8*75%29) seems to be $0.3414$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you need to look at $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 75, p = .2).$
Then the desired probability is $P(X \le 13).$ The normal approximation will be based on $\mu = np$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$ and the continuity correction
will use $P(X \le 13.5).$

The exact binomial answer from R statistical software is 0.3414, which would be tedious to find by using the formula for the binomial PDF and
adding probabilities $P(X=0) + P(X=1) + \cdots + P(X=13).$

```
pbinom(13, 75, .2)
## 0.3414021
```

A normal approximation using R gives 0.3325, but you will get a slightly
different approximation if you standardize and use printed normal tables.

```
n = 75; p=.2; mu=n*p; sg=sqrt(n*p*(1-p))
pnorm(13.5, mu, sg)
## 0.3325028
```

In this problem the normal approximation is rough, you can see from the graph below that the normal approximation is a little too small. I will leave details of computing the normal approximation from tables to you. Here is a start:

$$P(X \le 13) = P(X \le 13.5) = 
P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{13.5-15}{3.464}\right)
\approx P(Z \le ??) = ??$$

[image]

*Note:* As @David comments, you correctly found $P(X = 13),$ but that is
not the answer to the question.